# Using rails ActionView::TemplateRenderer to render a template without a request or session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I need to render some Rails HAML templates without a request or session.

I found this class: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView/TemplateRenderer

... but I'm not having much luck with it.

I can't figure out what to pass as the "local_context" argument to the constructor (which is defined in ActionView::AbstractRenderer).

Can someone provide a little working example of how to use this class? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A friend passed this link along, which turns out to work for my needs.

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html

I'd still be interested in knowing how to use ActionView::TemplateRenderer, though, as it seems to offer support for more formats and probably has other advantages.

Answer (score 0):

A google search including the phrase "render rails view in rake task" turned up a number of solutions, of which this one seems best:

http://mamykin.com/2011/06/28/how-to-render-view-from-rake.html